# Apache Server, How to specify a xml page on ErrorDocument

Tags: xml, apache, error-handling, errordocument

is there any way to specify a xml page on ErrorDocument?

In my default-ssl.conf I have:

```
<Location /mySite/>
                    ErrorDocument 403 /CustomErrors/error403.xml
</Location>
```

The error403.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MW_ERROR_RESPONSE>
    <MW_VERSION>1.0</MW_VERSION>
    <MW_ERRORDESC>Client Error Request - You are not authorized to access</MW_ERRORDESC>
</MW_ERROR_RESPONSE>
```

And when I try to access to the site, Apache server answers with the typical html saying in a part this:

```
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request
```

So I suppose that on ErrorDocument is only allowed to specify html pages.

Thank you.

Comment: The error message is clear enough. Your URL to the error document is wrong.

Comment: I've placed the xml file in the root directory, but I've also the same problem. So, could the problem be a permissions issue or is there any other configuration that I've forgotten?